# How to check query result is null

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I want to check query result. If it's  null I want to send data to DB. In my code even if result is null I can't update database.

```
    $this->db->where('login',$data_db['login']); 
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if(is_null($query)) // If Login doesn't exist in DB
    {
      $this->db->insert('users', $data_db); // Insert into DB
    }
}
```

I was trying to do that in other way but If user doesn't exist I got "Trying to get non object etc"

Other way:

```
$this->db->where('login',$data_db['login']);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
$row = $query->row();
if($row->login) 
{
    $this->load->view('content/error'); 
}
else
{
    $this->db->insert('users', $data_db);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest read through user guide before you post a question again you may find what your looking for.

Try n [$query->num_rows()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=num_rows#CI_DB_result::num_rows) userguide

```
public function somefunction($data_db = array()) {

$this->db->where('login',$data_db['login']); 

$query = $this->db->get('users');

if($query->num_rows() > 0){
   return TRUE;
} else {

   $this->db->insert('users', $data_db);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what im looking for. I never used num_rows thats why my question is so stupid for ppl.

Answer (score -1):

could always just do this

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query)==0) {your code if its null}
```